# Add values in dynamic inputs using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the help of http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/jQuery/jQuery-add-remove-textbox.html , I got my dynamic inputs and value.

But while adding its concatenating or getting `Nan`. I need to add values.

```
  var counter = 2;
  $("#addButton").click(function () {

      if(counter>20){
          return false;
      }

      var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

      newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
          ' <div class="col-md-6 marg-top-10 "> <input type="text" class="form-control inputData" name="assetDescription' + counter +
          '" id="assetDescription' + counter + '" value="" > </input> </div>' + 
          ' <div class="col-md-6 marg-top-10 "> <input type="text" class="form-control inputData" name="textbox' + counter +
          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" > </input> </div>'
      );

      newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
      counter++;
  });

  $("#removeButton").click(function () {
      if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
      }

      counter--;

      $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
  });
```

for adding value

```
 $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {
    console.log("came ");

    var msg = '';
    var totalvalue;
    var result;

    for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
        msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
        result += Number($('#textbox' + i).val());       

        console.log(result);
    }
```

result is = `Nan`

help please!

Comment: I test your link, but here are everything is ok. see screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ck769b

Comment: You can use parseInt instead of Number as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this..

```
var result = 0;
for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
            msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
            result += Number($('#textbox' + i).val());       
                      console.log(result);
      }
```

Comment: Thank you sarath!!

Comment: @Loading.. simply initialised the variable as number :)